# Event isn't executed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with MySQL event. I generated database dynamically using queries which are defined in SQL script. Database is created correctly. My event should change value of column after passing the time but it doesn't work as I want. After creating database event doesn't update values even if the condition is right. But when I open phpMyAdmin and run this event manually by click on "Execute" it work good since this moment and update values dinamically. This is my SQL query which define event:

> CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`hostName` EVENT `changeStatus` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND STARTS '2016-01-01 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO CALL checkFinished

And I added query which set event_scheduler variable:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 'ON'
```

Have anyone idea what should I do? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you do `SHOW PROCESSLIST` do you see the event scheduler task? Some MySQL servers don't have it running.   Also, a one second schedule? That's really often!

Comment: Can you post the SQL Script to see the whole process of creation and help you better?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no log history for events. What I would do to debug is to create a logging table and write in there when your event fires and if that works, also write in there the results (number of found records that meet the condition). So that you get closer to finding the issue of it. Difficult to say like what the problem might be.